# $_POST empty on form submit

Tags: php, post

I looked around this site already and it appears I'm not the only one who has this problem, but I couldn't find a solution that works. I have an incredibly simple form:

```
 <form action="inquiry.php" method="post" >
 Email Address:
 <input name="email" size="40" type="text" />
 <input value="Send" type="submit" />
 </form>
```

And the processing by PHP is a single line:

```
<?php mail('sample@example.com', 'Inquiry', $_POST['email']); ?>
```

I've confirmed that the data is sent to the server and that the emails are in fact sent but $_POST (as well as $_REQUEST) are in fact empty. I also checked and I see that `magic_quotes_gpc()` is in fact on but I do not know if that is the issue nor how to resolve it.

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc()` is bad and you should fire your host, but it shouldn't be causing this issue.

Comment: Given that you didn't copy the code directly, the problem may be fixed in SO so it may not be solvable by us.

Comment: The HTML is directly copied and now the PHP matches what I'm using exactly (with the exception of the actual email address).

Comment: Try using Chrome Developer Console's Network Inspector. Check that: Request Method:POST", and that Form Data includes the email. In addition check the version of PHP your host is using. In the unlikely event it's before 4.1.0, `$_POST` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipWhitehouse, turns out the default version of PHP is PHP4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start, many thanks to @PhilipWhitehouse for pointing me in the right direction.

For anyone that might be encountering this problem, **check your PHP version.** For some reason, 1&1 web hosting (and probably many others) have the default version set to PHP4 but you can change it to PHP5. God knows why they do that but its definitely something to check.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma in your mail line:

```
<?php mail('sample@example.com', 'Inquiry', $_POST['email']); ?>
```

This will send an email to sample@example.com with a subject of Inquiry and a body of $_POST['email'];

Comment: You're missing a right square bracket in your mail line. You need `$_POST['email']);` :) (How's that for irony, pointing out one mistake and introducing another?)

Comment: I miswrote it in SO; it's fine in my code. I'll update the question now.